# Enabling depth reigstration

Tags: ros, openni.launch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch, then rosrun dynamic_reconfigure reconfigure_gui, I select /camera/driver, but nothing shows up on the reconfigure window, and the following error is shown on the openni.launch terminal:

> [ERROR] [1365395678.038589497]: Client
> [/reconfigure_gui_13810_1365391644607]
> wants topic
> /camera/driver/parameter_descriptions
> to have datatype/md5sum
> [dynamic_reconfigure/ConfigDescription/757ce9d44ba8ddd801bb30bc456f946f],
> but our version has
> [dynamic_reconfigure/ConfigDescription/5f0f929417f58ac7f30dfdd9e4d40ef2].
> Dropping connection.

What is wrong?

Thank you very much for your help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60196/enabling-depth-reigstration/) by [Chik](https://answers.ros.org/users/3814/chik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 229 on 2013-04-07

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thank you very much, Philip. I discovered the reason. I am using Electric in Turtlebot laptop but Fuerte in workstation. Perhaps the datatype changes when the ROS version changes. I run dynamic_reconfigure from the turtlebot laptop, then it is okay. And in rviz (run from workstation) the registered point cloud looks very nice.

---

Originally posted by [Chik](https://answers.ros.org/users/3814/chik/) with karma: 229 on 2013-04-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't know about the problem, but if you just want to (statically) enable registration, you can edit your openni.launch file.

Change

```
<arg name="depth_registration" default="false" />
```

to

```
<arg name="depth_registration" default="true" />
```

to enable depth registration by default.

---

Originally posted by [Philip](https://answers.ros.org/users/4292/philip/) with karma: 990 on 2013-04-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1